# Plots.jl - Turn off axis and grid lines

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am trying to make a surface plot without the axis and grid lines. I found that I can turn off the grid with `grid = false` but I can't find a way to remove the axis lines.

```
surface(x2d, y2d, z2d, fill_z = color_mat, fc = :haline, grid=false)
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can almost but not quite get rid of them with `ticks = false`.

Comment: So you can't actually get rid of them?

Comment: So, a cheap trick... I ended up setting the foreground color to `:white`... Any plans to make them go away entirely with `ticks = false`?

Comment: It's actually a bug on plotlyjs that `ticks = false` makes the axes go away (but not the ticks!). I think your 'cheap trick' is actually the better option, possibly the best at the moment. Agreed it'd be nice to have this functionality. You'd be welcome to open an issue at the repo :-)

Answer (score 12):

`axis=([], false)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try `showaxis = false`, as described in the [axis attributes documentation](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_axis/).

Here's an example that works for me (in the Plotly backend).

```
surface(-10:10, -10:10, (x, y) -> x^2 - y^2, showaxis = false)
```