# Remove only axis values in plot Julia

Tags: julia, axis-labels, julia-plots

In R you can use this to remove the axis values:

```
x <- 1:20
y <- runif(20)
plot(x, y, axes=FALSE, frame.plot=TRUE)
Axis(side=1, labels=FALSE)
Axis(side=2, labels=FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608878/plots-jl-turn-off-axis-and-grid-lines), you can remove the axis values and tick marks like this:

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("Plots")
using Plots
# generating vectors
# x-axis
x = 1:10
 
# y-axis
y = rand(10)
 
# simple plotting
plot(x, y, ticks = false)
```

Output:

[image]

Is it possible to only remove the values of the axis while keeping the tick marks like in the R example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
plot(x, y, formatter=(_...) -> "")  #or:
plot(x, y, formatter=Returns(""))
```

`formatter` (and `xformatter`, `yformatter`) specifies a function which formats the axis labels.