# What is the purpose of the Returns() function in Julia?

Tags: julia

Julia 1.7 added the `Returns()` function which is described as:

> Create a callable `f` such that `f(args...; kw...) === value` holds.

However, you can get the same results with a regular function that accepts any arguments:

```
f1 = Returns(99)
f2(args... ; kwargs...) = return 99
f1() === f2()                                       # true
f1("this", 1) === f2("that", 2)                     # true
```

Is there some other purpose for `Returns()` other than being a shortcut for creating a function that returns a fixed result? The [PDF documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuliaLang/docs.julialang.org/assets/julia-1.8.3.pdf) doesn't explain `Returns()` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find `Returns` quite useful in cases when some API requires a function, but you need a constant value.

Here is an example in combination with DataFrames.jl. Let us take some data frame and add a constant column to it:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x=1:4)
4×1 DataFrame
 Row │ x
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     2
   3 │     3
   4 │     4

julia> transform(df, Returns(1))
4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      x1
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      1
   2 │     2      1
   3 │     3      1
   4 │     4      1
```

(there are other ways to do this operation, but this shows a case when it is useful to have - the `transform` function expects a function)

A more advanced aspect of its use is making a closure:

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> y = Returns(x)
Returns{Vector{Int64}}([1, 2, 3])

julia> y()
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> push!(x, 100)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
   1
   2
   3
 100

julia> y()
4-element Vector{Int64}:
   1
   2
   3
 100
```

and as you can see return value of `y` is updated if the underlying vector bound to `x` is mutated. Note that this capturing is type stable.

See also the discussion in [the PR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/39794) that introduced it and an example usage in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842089/remove-only-axis-values-in-plot-julia) on SO.